# "Your chance to dream has arrived" - National Lottery. How do you read this?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slogan

To me, that means: I can start dreaming after buying a lotto ticket. This is weird because without the lotto ticket, I can have my day-dream anyway. 
Shouldn't this be something like "your chance to realize your dream has arrived"?

This slogan kind of gives me the opposite feeling about buying a lotto ticket, as if it is always nothing more than a day-dream to win the lottery.

Comment: I read it as meaning "You dream, we'll profit from those dreams.  You'll end up with a nightmare."  (It's ad copy -- it isn't supposed to make sense.)

Comment: (Understand that if they said anything more substantial they'd have to admit that your chance of winning the lottery is even more insubstantial than a dream.  They're forced to use vague statements.)

Comment: It's not about dreaming of winning the lottery, it's about dreaming that you hold the winning ticket- which you can't do unless you buy one.  Between the time you  buy the ticket and the time you check the winning numbers there's a non-zero chance that you may actually have won.  But as another of their slogans says: You can't win if you don't play.

Comment: I read it as a bad ad agency, passing off tripe as a substitute for quality sloganeering. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sloganeering

Comment: @Jim - You can't lose if you don't play.

Comment: @HotLicks- Also true.  I'm just explaining, not advocating.

Comment: For an advert about gambling to be legal, decent, honest and truthful, shouldn't it include a proportionate number of comments by/about the many people who just lose money? 'Dream on' seems more appropriate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You lost me at "decent".

Comment: @MetaEd 'Legal, decent, honest and truthful' was(?) a set phrase when some UK Govt agency was asking people to report ads they considered not to be.

Answer (score 3):

I take a darker view of the slogan. It seems to me that it is urging potential lottery ticket buyers to accept that buying a ticket in hopes of winning the lottery is the only "chance to dream" that they have. It's hard to think of creepier and more cynical sales hook than that—particularly a sales hook associated with a less-likely-than-being-struck-by-lightning chance of hitting it big.

The psychology of sales pitches for lotteries is fascinating. As Jim notes in a comment above, a longstanding pitch for the Maryland Lottery (I believe) was "Ya gotta play to win!" which frames the purchase as a form of play involving a simple, exciting game. Likewise, other ad campaigns for lotteries, casino gambling, etc., focus on inviting prospective gamblers to "join the fun."

When I lived in New York City—a town whose denizens pride themselves on their street-smart, I'm-no-patsy outlook—a series of radio ads for the lottery adopted the tactic of asking everyday people why they "play the lottery." One memorable answer came from a native New Yorker who said "So I risk a buck—figure I might get lucky!" Just the right tone of not expecting to win (the way a chump would) but emphasizing that the stakes were so low ("a buck") that gambling actually made a kind of tough-guy sense. I waited in vain for one of the respondents to say, "Are you kiddin'? I really think I'm gonna win!"

Answer (score 2):

This slogan doesn't really apply to buying the lotto ticket itself. It is really meaning that here is your chance to dream about *winning the lottery* itself. So the slogan could really be like this:

> “Your chance to dream on winning the lottery has arrived”

As the OP said, this works as well:

> Your chance to actually win the lottery has arrived

I hope this helps you!

Comment: do they not actually mean 
"Your chance to actually win the lottery has arrived"?
“Your chance to dream on winning the lottery has arrived” still feels like that it is just a dream on winning. And worse, it is by chance.

Comment: @user2001850 Your interpretation is a valid parsing of the sentence (from a grammatical perspective), but it was not the **intended message** when the ad was coined. The intended meaning is closer to "Be thankful for the National Lottery, its existence is a good justification for you to dream about becoming filthy rich". In other words, without the lottery, you'd have no **valid** reason to dream about being rich (because there would be no way for you to become rich without the National Lottery). That's of course not correct, but it's what the ad tries to convey anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand: "We are selling you a dream. Come and buy the ticket and the dream starts immediately".

Answer (score 1):

I read it as a rephrase of every-other piece of mail I received in the '80's:

> "You ***may*** have already won a million dollars!"